# Is there a way to create a mutable reference for a type that doesn't match underlying storage?

Tags: rust, reference, mutable, unsafe

Consider a struct that is implemented as a `[u8; 2]`. Is it possible to construct a `&mut u16` mutable reference to the whole struct? Is there a safe way to do it?

As an alternative way of phrasing this, is there a way to implement:

```rust
fn ref_all(&mut [u8; 2]) -> &mut u16
```

Is there a way to do this in general for custom types as well?

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfectly safe method to do this, but there is [`align_to_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to_mut) (and its immutable counterpart `align_to`) defined for slices, which works for all types and is a safer alternative to the big hammer of `mem::transmute`:

```rust
fn ref_all(x: &mut [u8; 2]) -> &mut u16 {
    let (prefix, chunks, suffix) = unsafe {x.align_to_mut::<u16>()};

    // you don't need these asserts but know that chunks might not always have an element
    assert!(prefix.is_empty());
    assert!(suffix.is_empty());
    assert_eq!(chunks.len(), 1);

    &mut chunks[0]
}
```

For `u16`s, this should be fine, although it can cause architecture-dependent behavior due to the endianness of numbers. For other types it'd be very risky to do something like this.